# Permanently saving data using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made a ToDo list app where I enter a task in one view controller and it saves the data in array of another view controller and then adds it to a table. My only problem is that when I close the app, all my new task data is gone. Can anyone help?

I tried using UserDefaults but it didn't work quite well or I just didn't use it right.

This is the code from the view controller where I type in the new task:

```
@IBAction func addTaskButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    if (textField.text != "") {
        Task.append(textField.text!)

        let task = UserDefaults.standard.set(Task, forKey: "XX")

        textField.text = ""
        textLabel.text = "SAVED!"
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.6, target: self, selector: #selector(AddTaskViewController.Hide), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        textLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

This is the code from the view controller where I try to save the Data and place it in a table

```
var Task = ["Pray", "Code", "Work-Out"]
var School = ["Email Collin College","Email PQC","Create file for all my doccumensts"]
var ShoppingList = ["KD9 Black","RoshRun Black","Nike Huarache Black","White Shirt","Black Shirt", "Black Work Out pnats", "White Socks"]
var Prayer = ["School","Family","Drive & Grace"]
var WorkOut = ["Legs","Caffs","Push Ups","Arms","Chest Press","Squats", "Back"]

class add_Task_TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var TaskTableView: UITableView!

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (Task.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = Task[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        {
            Task.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            TaskTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        TaskTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: By using UserDefaults what exact problem do you faced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLITE as a database where you maintain your draft messages or values that can be used later when you open app again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use userDefaults to save your todo List. But what you are missing is you are storing correctly but you are not retriving stored array from the userDefaults.

To solve this just change your viewDidAppear method as below code snippet.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    Task = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "XX") ?? [String]()
    TaskTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `UserDefaults` is not the place to save app data.

Comment: Yeah you are right @rmaddy, it is not the correct place to store huge data as it is there to store little amount of data like user preferences. In Perewillz question i assumed todo list per a user does not generate that much huge data, because after the task is completed it will be deleted from the list this is a general todo list apps does.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/users/6643110/krishnarjun-banoth!!

Comment: Glad to here from you.  Accept the worked answer, so that others can use it in future.